# cast and substring

Tags: sql, ssis, substring

I'm having a little bit of trouble trimming my join keys for an SSIS transformation.

```
SELECT year_time, substring(rtrim(cast(region_code+county_code+district_code as varchar(100)), 5,4)as DR, rtrim(ltrim(T1.district_name)) as 'DNR', SUM(CAST(K12 AS INT)) AS 'TR'   
FROM Database_Table
GROUP BY year_time, region_code+county_code+district_code, district_name
order by year_time, district_code_raw, district_name_raw
```

I'm getting an error that my rtrim function requires 1 argument.  I believe the error is on the concatenation.

Comment: Are you getting error? What is the trouble?

Comment: I have no idea what your question is here. You didn't ask one, and didn't say what the trouble is...

Comment: rtrim function requires 1 argument

Comment: `The rtrim function requires 1 arguments.` you have it getting 3 `rtrim(cast(region_code+county_code+district_code as varchar(100)), 5,4)`  Also, it would be helpful if next time you give the error message you receive along with what you are attempting to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a parentheses to close the `RTRIM()`:

```
SELECT year_time, 
    substring(rtrim(cast(region_code+county_code+district_code as varchar(100))), 5,4)as DR, 
    rtrim(ltrim(T1.district_name)) as 'DNR',                                 --^--missing
    SUM(CAST(K12 AS INT)) AS 'TR'   
FROM Database_Table
GROUP BY year_time, region_code+county_code+district_code, district_name
order by year_time, district_code_raw, district_name_raw
```

Comment: Thank you.  I was staring at this and needed additional eyes for this simple mistake.

Comment: @Tone Whenever you get something like that you can always format the code to see the opening/closing parentheses.